# Angular 2 file upload to REST API by form-data

Tags: angular, typescript

When using form-data to upload file with other form inputs, it does not accept the integer. When we pass the integer values, it converts as string. But i need to pass integer i.e. numbers, string and file upload to REST API by form-data. Can anyone please suggests for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your code such that we can find possible bugs!

Comment: Thanks. Actually am not getting error. When using formdata, it converts the integer as string. But in REST API it expects those value as integer. So i need to know how to pass integer value in formdata.

Comment: Well, if you don't show us your code, we cannot see where stuff is going wrong....

Answer (score 0):

```
 Save(model: yourmodalarray[]): Observable<any> {

        var formData: FormData = new FormData();

        formData.append('id', '');
 const headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


        return this._http
            .post(this._baseUrl + 'Save', formData, options)
            .map(res => <any>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Use append method to pass the integer value.i hope this help...

Comment: Sorry. When append the integer value to form data, it shows error. To resolve that error i need to convert it as string. But i need that value to pass as integer.

Comment: please share your code,then only we can solve this issue